# Single plot commands

Tags: r, command

Is it possible to condense a large set of information into a single command in R such as `graph 1`? I have provided the information I wish to condense but due to the separate functions e.g. points and legend, I am finding it difficult.

```
plot(temp.a~Response,data=sst.brazil.bleach,pch=15, col="red", ylim=c(0,6),xlim=c(0,30), main="Fig. 1. The effect of anomalous levels of sea surface temperature on coral bleaching",xlab="Bleaching response index",ylab=" Total annual sea surface temperature anomalies\n(°C)")
points(temp.a~Response,data=sst.seychelles.bleach,pch=16, col="blue")
points(temp.a~Response,data=sst.indo.bleach,pch=17, col="orange") 
legend("bottomright", bty= "n", c("Brazil","Seychelles","Indonesia"),col=c('red', 'blue', 'orange'),pch=c(15,16,17))
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a function that draws your plot with only one command `myplot()`:

```
myPlot <- function(myTitle="Fig. 1. The effect of anomalous levels of sea surface temperature on coral bleaching") {
  plot(temp.a~Response,data=sst.brazil.bleach,pch=15, col="red", ylim=c(0,6),xlim=c(0,30), 
       main=mytitle,
       xlab="Bleaching response index",ylab=" Total annual sea surface temperature anomalies\n(°C)") 
  points(temp.a~Response,data=sst.seychelles.bleach,pch=16, col="blue") 
  points(temp.a~Response,data=sst.indo.bleach,pch=17, col="orange") 
  legend("bottomright", bty= "n", c("Brazil","Seychelles","Indonesia"),
         col=c('red', 'blue', 'orange'),
         pch=c(15,16,17))
}

myplot()
myPlot("I want another title for this one")
```

Or could also save the plotting commands into a seperate file, e.g. `myplot.r`, and call it using

```
source("myplot.r")
```

The article [Designing projects](http://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-05-projects/) helped me to get a little more organized in R. Maybe it helps you, too.

Comment: what function would you recommend for this example?